# Assign GameViewController as datasource for SceneKitView

Tags: swift, core-data, scenekit

I'd like to use Core Data in a SceneKit application, but when creating the project there was no option to check "Use Core Data" after selecting File, New ->
 Project -> Game; and if I try to add Core Data to the project after creating it, I cannot connect the SceneKitView "datasource" to the GameViewController (the only Outlet option listed when control dragged to VC is "delegate").

Am I not supposed to use Core Data with SceneKit? Is there a better method of storing a relatively simple data model involving two related tables with one to many relationship between them?

Comment: Can you add some more details on what exactly you want to store, what is in the scene, how many objects etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Core Data in any type of project including SceneKit based. It's however in most cases not as plug and play as with a tableviewcontroller, a SCNView does not have a datasource. Instead, you have to create your managed objects manually, which are an abstract of the objects you want to store with only the properties you want to store. Everytime you add/delete/modify a node or the scene itself, you need to update the corresponding object in the context manually. As mentioned in my comment, please update your question with more details on what you want to store and also how much of it as that can help determine alternatives. There are quite a few alternatives such as saving to plist, serialize the entire scene, and obj file export (with possibly some custom fields in the .mtl file).